# Sequelize and Postgres; how to set a value boundary (total min/mac); and/or run validation on updates

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a sequelize model with postgres and I need a value that has a min and max constraint on the total value.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');

class Service extends Sequelize.Model {}
Service.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true
      }
    },
    seats: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        min: 0,
        max: 400,
        isBelowZero(value) {
          if (value < 0) {
            throw new Error('Can not be below zero!');
          }
        }
      }
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  {
    sequelize: db,
    modelName: 'service'
  }
);

module.exports = Service;
```

The "seats" property needs to have a total minimum of 0 and a total max of 400. When I create the database entries the validators work. But say the value is at 5 and I decrement the value by 7 it is now -2 in the database table. But I need it to error, because the value is below 0.

I am used to Mongoose and MongoDB and it just works with this. On update their is a runValidation option and it throws an Error if the new value is below zero or above 400.

Comment: Are you updating records using database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Seuqeulize Hooks.
Add a hook to your model at the model definition:

```js
Service.beforeUpdate((service, options) => {
    if (service.seats < 0 || service.seats > 400) {
        throw new Error("Seats can be in [0, 400] range!");
    }
});
```

This, of course, will rollback the update.

For more details about sequelize hooks: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html